# VSCode Windows stops npm

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, visual-studio-code, lite-server

I have lite-server (2.3.0) running on a VSCode integrated terminal on my Mac and I have another integrated terminal for running gulp and publishing into my dist folder which is where lite-server is serving from.

Whenever I do that on my Mac it works nicely and the browser refreshes and lite keeps running. However when running exactly the same process on my Windows machine the lite-server process crashes getting:

```
code ELIFECYCLE
errno 1
```

and the error seems to be:

```
events.js:163
     throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
     ^

Error: EPERM: operation nor permitted, lstat
```

I have:

npm 4.4.1

node 7.8.0

vscode (running as admin as far as I know) 1.10

angular 4.0.1

It looks to me that it is a permission issue but I have run a separate CMD as admin and I get exactly the same behavior.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to VS Code when you `have run a seprate CMD as admin` with the same result.

Comment: You are right, probably has nothing to do with VSCode but it was to give full context of the issue and see whether someone else has faced the same problem